# Google maps setMap() and map options

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am new to Google maps api v3.
In the Google maps official tutorial, some of the sample code using

```
new google.maps.Marker({
 map: map    //Map option
});
```

or

```
new google.maps.Marker({
 //some options here
}).setMap(map);
```

What are the difference between each other?

Comment: the first will trigger an syntax-error(forced by the semicolon), while the second will trigger an error because of an undefined constructor `google.maps.Markers` (sarkasm)

Comment: @Dr.Molle good comment.Even I had  undefined constructor error

Comment: @Dr.Molle   type. should be ,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Off the top of head:

1. You can create markers and add them to a map at a later time e.g. after clicking some button using `setMap()`
2. You can have multiple maps on one page. You can selectively add markers to any one of them using `setMap()`
3. You can also remove markers selectively from a map using `setMap(null)`

Answer (score 1):

assuming you mean `google.maps.Marker` both codes finally result in exactly the same.

The first code initializes the Marker with a map-property, while the second code initializes the marker without the map-property and sets the map-property of the already initialized marker.

Comment: I guess he is asking which is better